# Material-UI and React IE11 compatibility

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, material-ui

I'm trying to implement material-ui in my React application. Unfortunately we still have to support IE, but anything material-ui I try to add makes the app not display, and with loads of undefined errors in the console. For example, I'm trying to add the Tabs component code directly from material-ui's site (using v4.8.3):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`nav-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`nav-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>}
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `nav-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `nav-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

function LinkTab(props) {
  return (
    <Tab
      component="a"
      onClick={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function Header() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          variant="fullWidth"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="nav tabs example"
        >
          <LinkTab label="Page One" href="/drafts" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <LinkTab label="Page Two" href="/trash" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <LinkTab label="Page Three" href="/spam" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Page One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Page Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Page Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but all I get in IE is many of these:

[image]

[image]

Is there something I am missing here? Any polyfills I need to add? Chrome displays just fine with no errors. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error you are showing does not match with the code you included (e.g. error indicates a `Header` component that you didn't provide the code for). Please show the exact error you get when using the simplest possible code for reproducing the error (preferably without any router or redux complexities) using code that is included in your question. I use Material-UI with IE 11 without any issue and I don't believe that Material-UI currently requires any polyfills for IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Supported Platform](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/) of Material-UI, it says *it also supports Internet Explorer 11. You don't need to provide any JavaScript polyfill as it manages unsupported browser features internally and in isolation.*

I made a demo using Tab component and the code you providing, it [works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0in7y.gif) in IE 11.  Maybe the error occurs in other codes and you could check again where the error points to. Besides, have you had the right package.json? I use **package.json** like below:

```
{
  "title": "Material demo",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  },
  "description": "https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/tabs/SimpleTabs.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.6",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest"
  }
}
```

You could refer to my [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nlk87q?file=demo.js). If the issue still persists, you could provide [a reproducible demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using online code editor like StackBiltz. I think that will help us have a better understanding of the issue and see how to help.